# Rspec/Capybara features tests not running, even with _spec.rb ending

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

When I run my Rspec feature examples, they are not being detected. When I specify the route to my /features folder, the message I get is " No examples found". I'm not sure if it's a requirement issue or something I'm missing with my test.

my feature test:

```
require "rails_helper"
require 'capybara/rspec'



feature "user creates student", :type => :feature do
background do
    user = create :user
scenario "with valid data" do
    visit '/students/new'
    within("form") do
        fill_in ":first_name", :with => 'jason'
        fill_in ":last_name", :with => 'foobar'
        fill_in ":user_id", :with => '1'
    end
    click_button 'Submit'
    expect(page).to have_content 'jason foobar'

  end
end


  feature "user cannot create student" do
   background do
    user = create :user
    scenario "with invalid data" do
    visit '/students/new'
    within("form") do
        fill_in ":first_name", :with => :nil
        fill_in ":last_name", :with => 'foobar'
        fill_in ":user_id", :with => '1'
    end
    click_button 'Submit'
    expect(studnt.errors[:first_name]).to include("can't be blank")

  end
end
 end


 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spec is getting run, but because it is malformed, there are no examples in it.

If you were to format it properly (e.g. in terms of indentation), it would be more clear, but your `background` blocks include both of the associated scenarios.

You need to delete the last two `end` statements in your file and insert `end` statements at the end of each `background`, as follows:

```
require "rails_helper"
require 'capybara/rspec'

feature "user creates student", :type => :feature do
  background do
    user = create :user
  end

  scenario "with valid data" do
    visit '/students/new'
    within("form") do
      fill_in ":first_name", :with => 'jason'
      fill_in ":last_name", :with => 'foobar'
      fill_in ":user_id", :with => '1'
    end
    click_button 'Submit'
    expect(page).to have_content 'jason foobar'
  end
end

feature "user cannot create student" do
  background do
    user = create :user
  end

  scenario "with invalid data" do
    visit '/students/new'
    within("form") do
      fill_in ":first_name", :with => :nil
      fill_in ":last_name", :with => 'foobar'
      fill_in ":user_id", :with => '1'
    end
    click_button 'Submit'
    expect(studnt.errors[:first_name]).to include("can't be blank")
  end
end
```